# How to write an xpath for a specific text from a whole attribute?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

So the problem statement is:

I need to store a specific number(marked in RED) from the attribute & for that I want to point to that number in an xPath. Is that possible? 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the `innerHTML` via `getAttribute("onmouseover")` function and parse the `String` using a regular expression. There is no direct approach from `Selenium`.

Answer (score -1):

You can ask for a link tag which contains some substring in its *onmouseover* attribute.

```
//a[contains(@onmouseover, '338792')]
```